# java web glassfish error port 8080 hello world

Tags: java, веб-программирование, intellij-idea, glassfish, port

Как запустить первое java web приложение? Работаю в intellij-idea на linux, создаю проект Java Enterprise, подключаю web application и сервер glassfish. Запускаю приложение и получаю 
`Error running GlassFish address localhost:8080 is already in use`. Похоже, надо изменить порт, но как, и поможет ли это?
Полагаю, код подразумевает стандартный пример "Hello, world" `web.xml` (http://pastebin.com/TW0XjFD0) и `index.jsp` (http://pastebin.com/D3GEJyvN). Код без вывода "Hello, world" в `body`, потому что пока стоит задача победить ошибку с портом. Код комплириуется, но не запускается.

Comment: вы бы написали листинг приложения,так было бы понятнее,что там происходит..

Comment: Стандартный набор файлов после создания проекта. Дополнил описание.

Comment: Да при чём тут web.xml и index.jsp? Вроде программы пишите на аглицкой языке, а понять ошибку не можете `Ошибка запуска glassfish - адрес localhost:8080 уже занят`. Ваш глазфиш не запускается, не говоря уже о xml и jsp. Ищите что там у Вас занимает этот адрес или меняйте адрес глазфишу.

Comment: у вас приложение состоит из классов.в классах есть код(который вы пишите в idea).покажите этот код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В директории `glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\config` открываем текстовым редактором `domain.xml` находим свой порт и меняем на другой. В моем случае был 8080, поставил 9999

Comment: Проблема решена, но появилась другая. После компиляции появляется процесс `kswapd0` и забивает всю оперативную память